# Optimizing LINQ Query on C# Web API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, query-optimization, asp.net-core-6.0

can you help me optimize this code especially the LINQ query. It takes 8-12 seconds just to return a response when I'm calling the endpoint. Its super slow, and my whole endpoint call is taking about 30 seconds since I have more functions to call after this. It is a big database that returns many rows and maybe someone can help me to optimize it or give me an advice on how to make it efficient and not take 8-12 seconds to complete. Thank you very much!

This is a function that I call from one of my endpoint.

```
public static void PrintSlip(IConverter _converter, AcommerceApiContext _context)
        {

            Helper ch = new Helper(_context);
            SODataProvider so = new SODataProvider();

            var lstOrder = ch.fillDataHeader();
```

This is the LINQ query that I've converted from SQL query to LINQ. I basically have 4 tables that I have joined so that I can access their properties. The part where I take just 1 in statuses is the part where I just need 1 recent row (based on eDate) from multiple rows with the same LineID but with different statuses.

```
public DataTable fillDataHeader()
        {
            var query = (from h in _context.orderHeaders
                         join l in _context.orderLines on h.HeaderId equals l.HeaderId
                         join u in _context.endUsers on h.ShipToId equals u.AddressId
                         join s in _context.orderStatuses on l.LineId equals s.LineId into statuses
                         from status in statuses
                         .Where(x => x.LineId == l.LineId)
                         .OrderByDescending(x => x.Edate)
                         .Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
                         where !l.IsDigitalGoods == true && h.SlipFlag == false && h.Attribute2 == null
                             && (!h.OrderStatus.Contains("cancel") && (status.StatusName == "pending" || status.StatusName == "ready_to_ship" || status.StatusName == "packed"))
                             && l.IsActive == true
                         orderby h.HeaderId descending
                         select new
                         {
                             //Add Order Date Here
                             HeaderID = h.HeaderId,
                             OrderNumber = h.OrderNumber,
                             StoreName = l.StoreName,
                             OrderDate = h.CreationDate,
                             SLATimestamp = l.Slatimestamp,
                             Marketplace = h.Attribute1,
                             Address = u.Address1 + (u.Address2 != "" ? ", " + u.Address2 : "") + (u.SubDistrict != "" ? ", " + u.SubDistrict : "") + (u.City != "" ? ", " + u.City : "") + (u.Province != "" ? ", " + u.Province : "") + (u.PostalCode != "" ? ", " + u.PostalCode : ""),
                             OrderStatus = h.OrderStatus,
                             SlipFlag = h.SlipFlag,
                             Addressee = u.Addressee
                         }).Distinct();

            DataTable lstOrder = new DataTable();

            // Add columns to the DataTable based on the properties in the query result
            lstOrder.Columns.Add("HeaderID", typeof(int));
            lstOrder.Columns.Add("OrderNumber", typeof(string));
            lstOrder.Columns.Add("StoreName", typeof(string));
            lstOrder.Columns.Add("OrderDate", typeof(string));
            lstOrder.Columns.Add("SLATimestamp", typeof(string));
            lstOrder.Columns.Add("Marketplace", typeof(string));
            lstOrder.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));
            lstOrder.Columns.Add("OrderStatus", typeof(string));
            lstOrder.Columns.Add("SlipFlag", typeof(bool));
            lstOrder.Columns.Add("Addressee", typeof(string));

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                lstOrder.Rows.Add(
                    item.HeaderID,
                    item.OrderNumber,
                    item.StoreName,
                    item.OrderDate,
                    item.SLATimestamp,
                    item.Marketplace,
                    item.Address,
                    item.OrderStatus,
                    item.SlipFlag,
                    item.Addressee
                );
            }


            return lstOrder;

        }
```

This is the Raw SQL query that I've converted to LINQ query above

```
SELECT *
                            FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY h.HeaderID
                                    ORDER BY h.HeaderID DESC) AA, h.*, h.Attribute1 Marketplace, 
                                    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CreationDate, 101) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CreationDate, 108) [OrderDate], u.Address1 + CASE WHEN u.Address2 != '' 
                                    THEN ', ' + u.Address2 ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN u.SubDistrict != '' THEN ', ' + u.SubDistrict ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN u.City != '' 
                                    THEN ', ' + u.City ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN u.Province != '' THEN ', ' + u.Province ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN u.PostalCode != '' 
                                    THEN ', ' + u.PostalCode ELSE '' END [Address],
                                    COALESCE(l.SLATimestamp, NULL) SLATimestamp,
                                    l.StoreName,
                                    u.Addressee 
                                FROM [OrderHeader] h 
                                INNER JOIN [OrderLine] l ON l.HeaderID = h.HeaderID 
                                LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by LineID ORDER BY EDate DESC)  AS AA,  *
                                                FROM OrderStatus) tbl 
                                            WHERE AA = 1) s ON s.LineID = l.LineID
                                INNER JOIN [EndUser] u ON h.ShipToID = u.AddressID WHERE l.[IsDigitalGoods] = 0 AND Slip_Flag = 0 AND h.ATTRIBUTE2 IS NULL 
                                    AND (  OrderStatus NOT LIKE '%cancel%' AND s.StatusName IN ('pending','ready_to_ship')) AND l.IsActive = 1) tbl
                            WHERE AA = 1 
                        ORDER BY HeaderID desc
```

I have tried many ways to modify the LINQ query but it doesn't have the same result with the result from the SQL query. The LINQ query above is the only one that returns the same result.

Comment: if too complex, why not use Stored Procedure, call from entity?

Comment: There's a lot to unpack in that query. "Contains" as well as "Order by" and "Distinct" are expensive functions in queries. Are there better ways to identify the order statuses you're after?

Comment: This seems like a better question for Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Refactor the SQL query into WITH statements for clarity.  They are called CTE Common Table Expressions.

For example, move the EndUser table part to its own query including the CASE statements.

Comment: I can correct this query but post classes definitions with navigation properties.

Comment: I recently had a similar issue and two things made a HUGE difference to the execution speed. Fist, make sure you have built an index on any columns you commonly use for searching (say in a `Where` clause), and second, if you ever have a Linq query that has a lot of `Include`s, consider adding a view to your database, and query that view. Made a massive difference for me

Comment: Plus, before you start, it's worth confirming exactly where the bottleneck is. Yes the query looks an obvious candidate, but you should run some tests and see what's actually taking the time. [You'd be surprised sometime](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: enable query logging feature of EF, take the generated query, paste it in sql server and investigate the execution plan. you will likely find a lot of problems. be sure to create necessary indexes

Comment: also if you don't like the query that EF is generating, you can always execute raw sql commands with EF https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries